# Fatal error : Class 'Imagick' not found Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, imagick

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

I've run following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo apt-get update
```

Edited my php.in **/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini** added following at end of file

```
extension=imagick.so
```

After all this

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But still I'm getting the error and even in php -m it's not showing Imagick.

Using

```
PHP 5.6.28-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay finally got solution..

```
 sudo apt-get install php5.6-imagick
 sudo service apache2 graceful
```